# How to rename Pytorch object name?

Tags: python, pytorch

My Pytorch Model:

```
EfficientDet(
  (backbone): EfficientNetFeatures(
    (conv_stem): Conv2d(4, 48, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(48, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
...
...
```

Is there a way to rename `backbone` object to some other name?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? Can you link us to where the names are documented?

Comment: Why would you want to change the name? It's just an attribute of the model, i.e. `model.backbone`. You could assign them to something else, but anything in the model that accesses `self.backbone`, such as in the forward method, relies on that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

We can rename an attribute of an instance using the following function.

```
def rename_attribute(obj, old_name, new_name):
    obj._modules[new_name] = obj._modules.pop(old_name)
```

**Example**

```
class EfficientNetFeatures(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EfficientNetFeatures, self).__init__()
        self.conv_stem = nn.Conv2d(4, 48, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                   stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(48, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1,
                                  affine=True, track_running_stats=True)


class EfficientDet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EfficientDet, self).__init__()
        self.backbone = EfficientNetFeatures()


model = EfficientDet()
print(model)

rename_attribute(model, 'backbone', 'newname')
print(model)
```

Outputs:

```
EfficientDet(
  (backbone): EfficientNetFeatures(
    (conv_stem): Conv2d(4, 48, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(48, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  )
)

EfficientDet(
  (newname): EfficientNetFeatures(
    (conv_stem): Conv2d(4, 48, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(48, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  )
)
```